How to shipping rates in stripe checkout api
#I am trying to build a ecommerce and I want to shipping rates in stripe ,But their documentation is confusing so I am using
line_items.push({
            
                price_data: {
                    currency: 'usd',
                    product_data: {
                        name: ( name.length > 100 ? name.substring(0,100) + '...' : name )
                    },
                    unit_amount: ((value,quantity,shipping)=> {
                        value =Number(value)
                        value +=(shipping/quantity);
                        value = value*100;
                        return value
                    })(value,quantity,shipping),
                },
                quantity: quantity
        })

##expecting to make stripe checkout with shipping rates


    let data = await createStripeCheckOut({
        line_items:line_items,
        success_url :'/api/api_s/stripe-order-success',
        cancel_url :'/api/api_s/stripe-order-cancel',
        amount_shipping:totalshipping
    })




export async function createStripeCheckOut({success_url,cancel_url,line_items ,amount_shipping}) {
    try {
        
    
    const session = await STRIPE.checkout.sessions.create({
    cancel_url:BASE_URL+cancel_url,
    success_url: BASE_URL +success_url,
    line_items:line_items,
    // [
    //     {
    //         price_data: {
    //             currency: 'usd',
    //             product_data: {
    //                 name: 'Node.js and Express book'
    //             },
    //             unit_amount: 50 * 100
    //         },
    //         quantity: 1
    //     },
    //     {
    //         price_data: {
    //             currency: 'usd',
    //             product_data: {
    //                 name: 'JavaScript T-Shirt'
    //             },
    //             unit_amount: 20 * 100
    //         },
    //         quantity: 2
    //     }            
    // ],
    mode: 'payment',
  /*  shipping_options: [
        {
          shipping_rate_data: {
            type: 'fixed_amount',
            fixed_amount: {
              amount: amount_shipping,//0
              currency: 'usd',
            },
            display_name: 'Free shipping',
            delivery_estimate: {
              minimum: {
                unit: 'business_day',
                value: 5,
              },
              maximum: {
                unit: 'business_day',
                value: 7,
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          shipping_rate_data: {
            type: 'fixed_amount',
            fixed_amount: {
              amount: amount_shipping,//0
              currency: 'usd',
            },
            display_name: 'Next day air',
            delivery_estimate: {
              minimum: {
                unit: 'business_day',
                value: 1,
              },
              maximum: {
                unit: 'business_day',
                value: 1,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ]*/
    
    });

    return session;
    } catch (error) {
        log(error)
        return false
    }

}


And the documentation of stripe and paypal sucks
And can anyone help me in this metter.Please describe you experience witn stripe

In order to implement Shipping Rates with Stripe Checkout, you should follow this guide.
Here is an updated version of your function:
export async function createStripeCheckOut({success_url, cancel_url, line_items, amount_shipping}) {
  try {
    const session = await STRIPE.checkout.sessions.create({
      cancel_url: BASE_URL + cancel_url,
      success_url: BASE_URL + success_url,
      line_items: line_items,
      mode: 'payment',
      shipping_options: [
        {
          shipping_rate_data: {
            type: 'fixed_amount',
            fixed_amount: {
              amount: amount_shipping,
              currency: 'usd',
            },
            display_name: 'Standard shipping',
            delivery_estimate: {
              minimum: {
                unit: 'business_day',
                value: 5,
              },
              maximum: {
                unit: 'business_day',
                value: 7,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    return session;
  } catch (error) {
    log(error);
    return false;
  }
}

